# Thread freezing in a while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

When compiling in GCC for release i get a strange behavior with threads in my algorithm. The thread doesn't leave the waiting loop even if the while condition changes, as if just died.

Another thing that i noticed is that if a `std::this_thread.sleep_for(10ms)` is inserted in the waiting loop it works properly or if i compile as debug it also works fine.

the following (pseudo)code is a very reduced version of the code.

```
bool some_data_ready = false;
bool lets_plot_data = false;

bytearray packets; // a dynamic bytearray that holds a stream of packets

void decode(){
    while(1){
        if(packets.size() > 200){ // packets has data to be decoded

            while (lets_plot_data) { //waiting loop
                /* on the second run it gets stuck here becuse thread 1 dont
                 * leave its locking loop even if lets_plot_data changes
                 */
                //this_thread.sleep_for(10ms);
            }

            for(int i = 0;i< packets.size();++i){
                if(packets.at(i) == 255){
                    if(packets.at(i+15) == 200){
                        //checks if packet has a start and an end
                        if(packets.at(14) == xor_checksum(packets.at(i))){
                            //packet is valid if calculated checksum is equal to the packet checksum
                            some_data_ready = true;
                            plot_data.push(packets.mid(i,15)); // copy a section starting at i len 15
                            // gets a packet and push it do be plotted
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(some_data_ready){
                lets_plot_data = true;
                some_data_ready = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

void plot(){
    while(1){
        while (!lets_plot_data) { //thread dont leave here even if lets_plot_data changes
            //this_thread.sleep_for(10ms);
        }
        graph.plot(plot_data); // not relevant, plots data at a graph
        lets_plot_data = false;
    }
}

std::thread* thread0;
std::thread* thread1;
std::thread* thread2;


int main(void){
    thread0 = new std::thread(data); // gets data to be decoded (stream of ubytes containing packets)
    thread1 = new std::thread(plot); // plot decoded data
    thread2 = new std::thread(decode); // decodes data to be ploted

    while(1){
        //"gui loop"
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If wondering, my release flags for GCC are

```
-Ofast -msse -fomit-frame-pointer -fmodulo-sched -fmodulo-sched-allow-regmoves -fgcse-sm -fgcse-las -fgcse-after-reload -funsafe-loop-optimizations -flive-range-shrinkage -fsched-spec-load-dangerous -fsched2-use-superblocks -floop-nest-optimize -floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=8 -fprefetch-loop-arrays -ffinite-math-only -march=native -mtune=native -mfpmath="387+sse" -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -static
```

but it also doesn't work for just a `-O2`

and works fine with `-g -Og` as strange as it may look

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It would be better to use [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Your loops load the processor with unnecessary work.

Comment: @boriaz50 im aware of them, but i still interested in why it gets stuck

Comment: Then use [std::atomic_bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious race condition on your flags:  you read and write `lets_plot_data` in the the thread that executes `plot()` and in the thread that executes `decode()` and nothing prevents this from happening at the same time.

You need to declare these flags atomic:

```
    atomic<bool> some_data_ready { false };
    atomic<bool> lets_plot_data { false };
```

If you're not yet familiar with this kind of issues, I recommend watching [this video from Herb Sutter](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2).

Comment: It was really it! it started working as i changed it the bools to  std::atomic_bool, i was not aware if this kind of atomic variables, thanks very much sir

Comment: @Ollegn I've added a link to a video to know more about this.